# Which software can replace ABCpdf?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

Currently, my server uses ABCpdf to generate PDF but my client wants to change to another software to generate PDF on the server (please see the list below).

- PDF Split and Merge
- CutePDF
- PDFSam
- ABBYY FineReader

I do a lot of searching on Google but it's still not clear. Could you give me a recommendation and advice for this?

Currently, we are using ABCpdf for generating PDF to users from doc files, image files, and to snapshot an URL then generate it to PDF.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: What operations, exactly, do you need to do? You mentioned converting .doc and image files to PDF as well as fetching a website to a PDF. Is there anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re looking for a library that can be used server-side to convert different image and document formats to PDF, one option is the [LEADTOOLS Document Imaging SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/document-imaging). (Disclosure: I'm a LEAD employee).

The SDK supports splitting, merging and converting, from and to PDF, among other features.

If you also need to convert text in images to searchable PDF, you can add the [OCR option](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/ocr) to the SDK.

There’s [a free evaluation edition](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads?category=main) you can try, which includes free tech support. So if there’s any feature you need and you’re not sure if it’s included in the SDK, you can contact support with your questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Syncfusion .Net PDF library](https://www.syncfusion.com/pdf-framework/net/pdf-library) to create, read, and edit PDF documents programmatically.

With this library you can convert [HTML](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/working-with-document-conversions#mhtml-to-pdf),[Word](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/working-with-document-conversions#converting-word-documents-to-pdf) and [Images](https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/9143/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-in-c-and-vb-net) to PDF.

Please find the some helpful links to get started.

- [HTML to PDF conversion](https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/9143/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-in-c-and-vb-net)
- [Word to PDF conversion](https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/9645/how-to-convert-word-to-pdf-using-c-and-vb-net)
- [Image to PDF conversion](https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/9541/how-to-convert-image-to-pdf-using-c-and-vb-net)

To find more details refer the [PDF help documentation](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/overview).

(Disclosure: I'm working for Syncfusion).